# Comparing columns with at least some values are the same Python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe with several rows and I need to assign a number (new column) according to the values of the other columns:

- If all values in the different columns are the same the new value would be 5,
- if at least 4 values are the same it would be 4,
- if at least 3 values are the same, 3
- and so on until all are different values and the new value would be 0.

```
  p1 p2 p3 p4 p5
0 1  1  1  1  1
1 2  3  2  2  2
2 2  2  3  4  1
3 4  4  1  1  1
4 2  1  2  3  5 
5 1  2  3  4  5
```

Output

```
 p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 new
0 1  1  1  1  1  5
1 2  3  2  2  2  4
2 2  2  3  4  1  2
3 4  4  1  1  1  3
4 2  1  2  3  5  2
5 1  2  3  4  5  0
```

For the first example where all are the same, I used np.where and it works:

```
df['new'] = np.where((df['p1'] == df['p2']) & (df['p1'] == df['p3']) & (df['p1'] == df['p4']) & (df['p1'] == df['p5']), 5, 0)
```

Comment: If you have  column values which repeat, how can you ever attain the last condition "and so on until all are different values and the new value would be 0."?

Comment: An example is in row 5(6), where all the columns have different values [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], so it will have 0. The first column is the index column, and it should not be taken into account for the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `collections.Counter` to count how many items are equal. I come up with this way:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

data = [
    [1,1,1,1,1],
    [2,3,2,2,2],
    [2,2,3,4,1],
    [4,4,1,1,1],
    [2,1,2,3,5],
    [1,2,3,4,5]
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['p1','p2','p3','p4','p5'])
print(df)

new_col = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    a = dict(Counter(df.iloc[i].tolist()))
    m = a[max(a, key=a.get)]
    if m > 1:
        new_col.append(a[max(a, key=a.get)])
    else:
        new_col.append(0)


df['new'] = new_col

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   p1  p2  p3  p4  p5  new
0   1   1   1   1   1    5
1   2   3   2   2   2    4
2   2   2   3   4   1    2
3   4   4   1   1   1    3
4   2   1   2   3   5    2
5   1   2   3   4   5    0
```

Comment: Thank you! @DeusDev This is really helpful. However, when I try to do this approach, in row 2 I'm getting a value of three instead of two. Do you know why this might be happening?

Comment: I don't know which values are you using for the original data columns. For the values you posted, you should obtain the output I showed.

Comment: Thank you! for some reason the first time I run it it gave other results, but now it worked! Thank you, really appreciated @DeusDev

Comment: You are welcome @Carmina. Consider accepting the answer if it was what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach from that suggested by @DeusDev would be:

```
def computeDiffs(rw):
    g = Counter(rw)
    m = max([g[x] for x in g.keys()])
    if m == 1:
        return 0
    return m
```

Then use:

```
df['new'] = df.apply(lambda row: computeDiffs(row), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you! @itprorh66 This is really helpful. However, same as with DeusDev approach, when I try to do this approach, in row 2 I'm getting a value of three instead of two. Do you know why this might be happening?

Comment: Because in row 2 = [2,2,3,4,1], there are 2 twos, 1 Three, 1 Four, and 1 One.